# error when parsing data from mysql table

Tags: android, mysql, json

I have my android app. which is suppose to let the user enter an area and then it goes and pull all organizations in my myqsl table and display it on the phone
but when I run the application I got this error:

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: 
  Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

here's my code:

JSONparser

```
        package com.example.islamicorg;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class JSONUseActivity extends Activity {


EditText byear;   // To take birthyear as input from user
Button submit;    
TextView tv;      // TextView to show the result of MySQL query 

String returnString;   // to store the result of MySQL query after decoding JSON

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
/* StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
.detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork() // StrictMode is most commonly used to catch accidental disk or network access on the application's main thread
.penaltyLog().build());*/
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

byear = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitbutton);
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showresult);

// define the action when user clicks on submit button
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){        
public void onClick(View v) {
// declare parameters that are passed to PHP script i.e. the name "birthyear" and its value submitted by user   
ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

// define the parameter
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("state",byear.getText().toString()));
String response = null;

// call executeHttpPost method passing necessary parameters 
try {
response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(
//"http://129.107.187.135/CSE5324/jsonscript.php", // your ip address if using localhost server
"http://10.0.2.2/android_login_api/include/islam.php",  // in case of a remote server
postParameters);


// store the result returned by PHP script that runs MySQL query
String result = response.toString();  


//parse json data
try{
returnString = "";
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("ID")+
", name: "+json_data.getString("Name")+
", phone: "+json_data.getInt("Telephone")+
", fax: "+json_data.getInt("Fax")+
", web: "+json_data.getString("WebAddress")+
", state: "+json_data.getString("state")+
", address: "+json_data.getString("Address")+
", mailing: "+json_data.getString("MailingAddress"));
//Get an output to the screen
returnString += "\n" + json_data.getString("Name") + "\n"+ json_data.getInt("Telephone")+ "\n"+ json_data.getInt("Fax")+ "\n"+ json_data.getString("WebAddress")+ "\n"+ json_data.getString("state")+ "\n"+ json_data.getString("Address")+ "\n"+ json_data.getString("MailingAddress");
}
}
catch(JSONException e){
Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
}

try{
tv.setText(returnString);
}
catch(Exception e){
Log.e("log_tag","Error in Display!" + e.toString());;          
}   
}
catch (Exception e) {
Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection!!" + e.toString());     
}
}         
});
}
}
```

and this is the http client

```
package com.example.islamicorg;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnManagerParams;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

import android.util.Log;

public class CustomHttpClient {

/** The time it takes for our client to timeout */

public static final int HTTP_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000; // milliseconds


/** Single instance of our HttpClient */

private static HttpClient mHttpClient;


/**

* Get our single instance of our HttpClient object.

* 

* @return an HttpClient object with connection parameters set

*/

private static HttpClient getHttpClient() {

if (mHttpClient == null) {

mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

final HttpParams params = mHttpClient.getParams();

HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);

HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);

ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);

}

return mHttpClient;

}


/**

* Performs an HTTP Post request to the specified url with the specified

* parameters.

* 

* @param url

*            The web address to post the request to

* @param postParameters

*            The parameters to send via the request

* @return The result of the request

* @throws Exception

*/

public static String executeHttpPost(String url,

ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters) throws Exception {

BufferedReader in = null;

try {

HttpClient client = getHttpClient();

HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(

postParameters);

request.setEntity(formEntity);

HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()

.getContent()));



StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");

String line = "";

String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");

while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

sb.append(line + NL);

}

in.close();


String result = sb.toString();

return result;

} finally {

if (in != null) {

try {

in.close();

} catch (IOException e) {

Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString()); 

e.printStackTrace();

}

}

}

}


/**

* Performs an HTTP GET request to the specified url.

* 

* @param url

*            The web address to post the request to

* @return The result of the request

* @throws Exception

*/

public static String executeHttpGet(String url) throws Exception {

BufferedReader in = null;

try {

HttpClient client = getHttpClient();

HttpGet request = new HttpGet();

request.setURI(new URI(url));

HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()

.getContent()));


StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");

String line = "";

String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");

while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

sb.append(line + NL);

}

in.close();


String result = sb.toString();

return result;

} finally {

if (in != null) {

try {

in.close();

} catch (IOException e) {

Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString()); 

e.printStackTrace();

}

}

}

}

}
```

this is my php script :

```
<?php
// PHP variable to store the host address
$db_host  = "localhost";
// PHP variable to store the username
$db_uid  = "admin";
// PHP variable to store the password
$db_pass = "123";
// PHP variable to store the Database name  
$db_name  = "android_app"; 
// PHP variable to store the result of the PHP function 'mysql_connect()' which establishes the PHP & MySQL connection  
$db_con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_uid,$db_pass) or die('could not connect');
mysql_select_db($db_name);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM islamic_organisation WHERE  state > '". $_POST["state"]."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
$output[]=$row;
$myFile = "testFile.txt"; $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file"); fwrite($fh, print_r($output,true)); fclose($fh);
print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();   
?>
```

any idea on how to solve that I'd appreciate that for you

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see the php code that is creating the json result that is returned...is the json correctly formatted? It looks like you're returning a string rather than an array.

Comment: You might try writing your variables to a file in the php script, then check that file to see what is being returned from your query...one way to troubleshoot, anyway.

Comment: how is that done dear?coz I'm really new. I got this cod from the internet and I edited it for my case.

Comment: something like: $myFile = "testFile.txt"; $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file"); fwrite($fh, $a_variable); fclose($fh); then you can look at testfile.txt

Comment: should I place it at the end of the script or some other place

Comment: I test it from the browser and also after I ran the app. but the file is still empty

Comment: Just anyplace where the variable has been given its value...you can move that code anywhere you want to see the state of a given variable

Comment: from the boser I see this Notice: Undefined index: state in C:\xampp\htdocs\android_login_api\include\islam.php on line 14
[{"ID":"1","Name":"abc","Telephone":"123","Fax":"127","WebAddress":"aer","state":"johor","Address":"fsfd","Mailing Address":"fsfsf"}]
Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\android_login_api\include\islam.php on line 20

Comment: but the txt file is empty and I have placed that code after print and before mysql_close()

Comment: now I got something in the txt file after I changed the piece of script u gave me to :                                          $myFile = "testFile.txt"; $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file"); fwrite($fh, print_r($output,true)); fclose($fh);        and I got this for the txt file                                  Array
(
    [0] => Array (
            [ID] => 1
            [Name] => abc
            [Telephone] => 123
            [Fax] => 127
            [WebAddress] => aer
            [state] => johor
            [Address] => fsfd
            [Mailing Address] => fsfsf)

)

Answer (score 0):

Which line is throwing the exception? I assume it is

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
```

If it is, it seems to me the server is feeding your app with XML data.

Comment: so dude what should I change to settle it !!

Comment: Your server code should produce JSON output, not XML. No server code was posted in the question at all.

Comment: there you go buddy..I edited the question and included the php code thanks a lot